# searching query in whole of world by foursquare venue api

Tags: search, location, foursquare

I take an string from user and must search its places in whole of world.

I want to use foursquare venues api.

but in that endpoint I must set search ranges by (ll and radius) or (sw and ne) or (near and radius).

now how search places for an string in whole of world ?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `intent` parameter to "global":

```
intent=global
```

See [Venue Search Parameters](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/search#parameters):

> *global*
>   Finds the most globally relevant venues for the search, independent of location.
>   Ignores all parameters other than query and limit.

For example:

> https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?intent=global&query=apple+store&oauth_token=(YOUR_TOKEN)&v=20150721

If you use the `global` value, all other parameters except `query` and `limit` are ignored.