# how to use foursquare search api to look for venues in the whole country not just my area

Tags: api, search, foursquare

Using the foursquare search api , https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

I need to search for a venue worldwide without having to specify a country, [so a user does not have to enter another field]

Is this possible to do with foursquare, or could you suggest any other services to do this?

Answer (score 1):

duplicate:[searching query in whole of world by foursquare venue api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885322/searching-query-in-whole-of-world-by-foursquare-venue-api/31552580)

Use intent=global parameter.

ex)
`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?intent=global&query=apple+store&oauth_token=(YOUR_TOKEN)&v=20150721`

If you use global parameter, all other parameters other than `query` and `limit` are ignored.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had been stuck on this problem for so long!!!!!